# Is it a uniform polyhedron?

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, geometry

## Objective

Given a [vertex figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_figure) consisting of regular convex polygons, determine whether it represents a convex [uniform polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polyhedron).

## What is a uniform polyhedron?

A uniform polyhedron is a polyhedron whose faces are regular polygons, while having the same vertex figure for each vertices. Generally a uniform polyhedron can be nonconvex, but only convex polyhedra will be considered in this challenge. (More precisely, the polyhedron is required to be vertex-transitive, but that's just another detail.)

## What is a vertex figure?

In the context of a convex uniform polyhedron, a vertex figure is a list of the number of edges of polygons (in order) around a vertex. For example, a cube has vertex figure of (4.4.4).

## Truthy inputs

> (3.3.3) – Tetrahedron
> (4.4.4) – Cube
> (3.3.3.3) – Octahedron
> (5.5.5) – Dodecahedron
> (3.3.3.3.3) – Icosahedron
> (4.4.N) for every N≥3 – N-gonal prism (It is a cube for N=4)
> (3.3.3.N) for every N≥4 – N-gonal antiprism (It is an octahedron for N=3)
> (3.6.6) – Truncated tetrahedron
> (3.4.3.4) – Cuboctahedron
> (3.8.8) – Truncated cube
> (4.6.6) – Truncated octahedron
> (3.4.4.4) – Rhombicuboctahedron
> (4.6.8) – Truncated cuboctahedron
> (3.3.3.3.4) – Snub cube
> (3.5.3.5) – Icosidodecahedron
> (3.10.10) – Truncated dodecahedron
> (5.6.6) – Truncated icosahedron
> (3.4.5.4) – Rhombicosidodecahedron
> (4.6.10) – Truncated icosidodecahedron
> (3.3.3.3.5) – Snub dodecahedron

Rotations and reversions (generally, all dihedral permutations) of these lists are also truthy. For example, (4.6.8), (4.8.6), (6.4.8), (6.8.4), (8.4.6), (8.6.4) are all truthy.

## Falsy examples

> (3.3.3.3.3.3) – Triangular tiling; not a polyhedron.
> (5.5.5.5) – Order-4 pentagonal (hyperbolic) tiling; not a polyhedron.
> (3.3.4.4) – Cannot be uniform. Note that this is different from (3.4.3.4).

## *Don't care* situations

An input is expected to have at least 3 entries, and to consist of integers that are at least 3. Otherwise, the challenge falls in *don't care* situation.

> (5/2.5/2.5/2) – Great stellated dodecahedron; not convex.
> (3.3) – Triangular dihedron; not Euclidean.
> (2.2.2) – Triangular hosohedron; not Euclidean.
> (3/2.3/2.3/2) – Retrograde tetrahedron.
> (1)
> (-3)
> ()

Comment: As I understand it, the Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra and uniform star polyhedra all have non-integer entries in the vertex figure, so they are not included, and the truthy inputs shown are *all* truthy inputs possible. Is this correct?

Comment: @fireflame241 Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>54</s>  51 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
2×þ5o6R¤
“EḶ¤ẊƓW4mð,’b6ṣ5ịþ¢Ẏṙ€Ƭ1Ẏ;U$e@
ṢṖ’Ḍe“!ṛ‘ȯÇ
```

A dyadic Link accepting a list of integers (each greater than two) which yields `1` if that list is a vertex figure which represents a uniform polyhedron, or `0` otherwise.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AXMAjP9qZWxsef//MsOXw741bzZSwqQK4oCcReG4tsKk4bqKxpNXNG3DsCzigJliNuG5ozXhu4vDvsKi4bqO4bmZ4oKsxqwx4bqOO1UkZUAK4bmi4bmW4oCZ4biMZeKAnCHhuZvigJjIr8OH////WzUsNCwzLDRd)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o8PTD@0zzzYIOLeF61DDH9eGObYeWPNzVdWxyuEnu4Q06jxpmJpk93LnY9OHu7sP7Di16uKvv4c6Zj5rWHFtjCGRbh6qkOnA93Lno4c5pQKUPd/SkAk1RfLhz9qOGGSfWH27/f7gdqPj//@hoYx0gjNWJNtEBQiAN5oNFTHWAECECV4WsGkSbQmkzKG0OpS0tzM3g2hFGI4xEyJrDWXBNZlBpE7hmCx0LsMkIGZgbzMAyMHdCVJvCrTI0ACKwfxA6TeE6wVIwraYI4xSADAuQeoVoM6AGCwjDAqRPIdoC4l0Qwww51JBDDu5RkCtjAQ).

#### How?

First, check if the input is any rotation or reflection of either `4,4,N` or `3,3,3,N` (using `ṢṖ’Ḍe“!ṛ‘`) - the prisms or antiprisms.

If not, build a table containing all the other un-permuted, possibilities - the Platonic and Archimedean solids. Then get all dihedral-permutations of that table's values (`Ẏṙ€Ƭ1Ẏ;U$`) and then check for the existence of the input (`e@`).

Note: The table actually built includes two redundant rows containing only lists which either contain some value(s) less than 3 or are of the form `4,4,N` in some rotation.

To build the table an outer-product using 1-based indexing is made between "items" vectors (of the form `r,2r,3,4,5,6`, where `r` is the row) and "indexes" vectors.

```
  | items        | indexes
--+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
r | r,2r,3,4,5,6 | 1,1,1 | 3, 2, 2 | 3,1,3,1 | 1,0,0 | 3,4,1,4 | 4,0,2 | 3,3,3,3,1
--+--------------×-------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------+----------
1 | 1, 2,3,4,5,6 | 1,1,1 | 3, 2, 2 | 3,1,3,1 | 1,6,6 | 3,4,1,4 | 4,6,2 | 3,3,3,3,1
2 | 2, 4,3,4,5,6 | 2,2,2 | 3, 4, 4 | 3,2,3,2 | 2,6,6 | 3,4,2,4 | 4,6,4 | 3,3,3,3,2
3 | 3, 6,3,4,5,6 | 3,3,3 | 3, 6, 6 | 3,3,3,3 | 3,6,6 | 3,4,3,4 | 4,6,6 | 3,3,3,3,3
4 | 4, 8,3,4,5,6 | 4,4,4 | 3, 8, 8 | 3,4,3,4 | 4,6,6 | 3,4,4,4 | 4,6,8 | 3,3,3,3,4
5 | 5,10,3,4,5,6 | 5,5,5 | 3,10,10 | 3,5,3,5 | 5,6,6 | 3,4,5,4 | 4,6,T | 3,3,3,3,5
```

The "indexes" vectors are encoded as a single base-6 integer which is split at its `5` digits (see the start of Link 2).

```
2×þ5o6R¤ - Link 1, Get the five "items vectors": no arguments
2        - two
   5     - five
  þ      - (implicit [1..2]) table (implicit [1..5]) using:
 ×       -   multiplication  -> [[1,2],[2,4],[3,6],[4,8],[5,10]]
     6R¤ - range of six -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    o    - logical OR (vectorises) -> [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,3,4,5,6],[3,6,3,4,5,6],[4,8,3,4,5,6],[5,10,3,4,5,6]]

“EḶ¤ẊƓW4mð,’b6ṣ5ịþ¢Ẏṙ€Ƭ1Ẏ;U$e@ - Link 2, Platonic or Achimedian?: list of integers (>2), V
“EḶ¤ẊƓW4mð,’                   - base 250 number = 269760427146828960006295
            b6                 - in base 6 = [1,1,1,5,3,2,2,5,3,1,3,1,5,1,0,0,5,3,4,1,4,5,4,0,2,5,3,3,3,3,1]
              ṣ5               - split at fives = [[1,1,1],[3,2,2],[3,1,3,1],[1,0,0],[3,4,1,4],[4,0,2],[3,3,3,3,1]]
                  ¢            - call Link 1 as a nilad = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,3,4,5,6],[3,6,3,4,5,6],[4,8,3,4,5,6],[5,10,3,4,5,6]]
                 þ             - table using:
                ị              -   index into -> the 5 by 7 table shown above
                   Ẏ           - tighten (to a list of the unpermuted lists)
                      Ƭ        - collect up until repetition applying:
                    ṙ€ 1       -   rotate each left one place
                        Ẏ      - tighten (to a list of all the rotations)
                           $   - last two links as a monad:
                          U    -   upend (reverse each list)
                         ;     -   concatenate (to the forward ones)
                            e@ - does (the input, V) exist in that list of lists?

ṢṖ’Ḍe“!ṛ‘ȯÇ - Main Link: list of integers (each >2), V
Ṣ           - sort V
 Ṗ          - remove the rightmost (maximal)
  ’         - decrement (each)
   Ḍ        - convert from base ten
     “!ṛ‘   - list of code page indices = [33,222]
    e       - exists in? (i.e. was V some rotation of [4,4,n] or [3,3,3,n]?)
          Ç - call Link 2 as a monad - f(V)
         ȯ  - logical OR
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 190 bytes

```python
def f(F):s="".join(hex(k)[2]for k in F);F[1:]in[[4,4],[3]*3]or{s,s[::-1]}&{*"555 333 366 388 3aa 466 566 468 46a 3434 3444 3454 3535 33333 33334 33335".split()}and max(F)<16or f(F[1:]+F[:1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRNj5swEL3zK6ZEqvAujcIa0igtx0Y99VCt1ANCESImcZfY1DYoaLW/PR0b8rHZlSrVBM@YmXl@nvGk6c1OCno8blgFVbAiS536/vS35CLYsUPwRLKHvJIKnoALWJEvqyxa5lxkWRzGeZjR/I7mUj3rUGfL5acof/n4fOcnSQKUUqDzOdDFAmhRQIx6gm88X@BbAI1pjFNspwSnhLoYG4UjdnPiT3VTcxOQl0JsYF8ckOHXaI58kKtlcr/KllFOjl1R88264oIbBilkHuDIkhAfyzLEx8l5OHdyES6cjGb4Qy0eLcko7XoxSusA9rz2xBOn/MiHDSjqdEhEODo4LRm1BK2JjXYMLAeYjPoF4mw76/GVnuRe7nm2PFyvW8GxGPugq8jShdvSdMbWJuuqELpqqEI@WE8e3DqoQmxZUDMRdIaQi4MdHeasMxnHhKJY8vyVlVfQWRvco0SjRbtO@GssOxQzrRLwqFp2i@QIEEhToGCL2mWzPE27LMI5/k@k@A1Sh9c2Tem/8cb1qqg1G9JsmDbrq1yvxlwZ1V9lFT97N5j@r10PPdMhbKXcgOYKMPf7YlPsQzC7AsukbeqqojS4ZtAxZdgBKr5tFQNZQQHjptDIut@xjZJi6rt92KFkjbkQmMBPVrZKcym@KSXVLZnxQBP4zuoGz6T2XBTYG39aXj7Vvcf3jVQGdK89fKeaGXXCq/keWy6aEc87uWGRlZGy1l5lcdeN1NzwjmnbazXXxt5Id9VK2QpzuW40/Dx87yr78YwzbZTctKUJXPDJN4oICRVrWGFSB0RsnW8LctqPuKoLaeA9Yz5SFWxbnKkiiwuZzDbo7Kr18M/AqvHD2MlDR@eWg93llgfugp3ZKC6Ma6ub1JA0nTmG/g8JzgZn2wefvAk8E30n8GyzgVjUR9XjZdENK3nFS9uMeJ0HwFuWl0MScvwL)

Takes input as a list of integers representing the vertex figure. The function [errors](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/68261) (`RecursionError`) if the vertex figure is *not* a uniform polyhedron, otherwise there is no error.

I tried several schemes of organizing the finite classes into a smart way that takes advantage of patterns, but hardcoding all possibilities reigned superior since it is a relatively small set.

#### Explanation

```python
def f(F):
    # F is a rotation of the input vertex figure; initially is the input vertex figure
    # Convert to string for easier comparison later in the code
    s="".join(hex(k)[2]for k in F)
    # Test true if the permutation is N.4.4.4 or N.3.3.3
    (F[1:]in[[4,4],[3]*3]or
    # Test truthy if permutation (or its reverse) is in
    #   3.3.3, 3.6.6, 3.8.8, 3.10.10, 4.6.6, 5.6.6, 4.6.8, 4.6.10,
    #   3.3.3.N, 3.4.3.4, 3.4.4.4, 3.4.5.4, 3.5.3.5
    #   3.3.3.3.3, 3.3.3.3.4, 3.3.3.3.5
    {s,s[::-1]}&{*"555 333 366 388 3aa 466 566 468 46a 3434 3444 3454 3535 33333 33334 33335".split()}
    # Numbers greater than 15 would convert into the most-significant hexit when converted to a string,
    # causing 0x43 to match the same as 0x4,
    # so we need to check that none of this happened if we want a bugfree string search
    and max(F)<16
    # If we tested truthy, then terminate
    # Otherwise, recurse with the vertex figure cyclically rotated left one
    or f(F[1:]+F[:1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 142 bytes

```
$
,$",
^`\G\d+,
$&
%L$`,
$'$>`
N^$`.+,(.+),
$1
N`
^(3,(3,3(,(\d+|3,[3-5]))?|4,([3-5],)?4|5,3,5|(6|8|10),\6)|4,4,\d+|4,6,(6|8|10)|5,(5|6),\8),¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU4xbgMhEOz3GRF2QDe2jBYQVVy6sfyBXE5Eios0KaKUvMsP8McuA/YlFit2mJkd9vv88/n17ueVPZTZCMwTZCrjYfwYIGYtq6MpBM/mpchpMmU7wG4HR8rLqchkFSy1sJyoilfdxDfn9jXAdgy3DzVCEatNNVe/cxiTox7QRgISFoE@G2uiITtcL/PMZKg0a5CO@YrgWV5dVape/0zek02MVWlkUzPvLO2rdEvrjvyf2lHfkt3vWD0h3tLZyaUH@8MCy0p3juG/) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
$
,$",
```

Duplicate the list and suffix a comma to each copy.

```
^`\G\d+,
$&
```

Reverse the first copy of the list.

```
%L$`,
$'$>`
```

Generate all rotations of both the list and its reverse.

```
N^$`.+,(.+),
$1
```

Sort the last number in descending order.

```
N`
```

Sort in ascending numeric order. (For the truthy cases, these two sorts ensure that the resulting first list is also the first list in list order.)

```
^(...),¶
```

Ensure the first list matches one of the truthy cases:

```
3,(3,3(,(\d+|3,[3-5]))?|4,([3-5],)?4|5,3,5|(6|8|10),\6)
```

Handle those cases with a `3`: `3,3,3`, `3,3,3,N` (`N>=3`), `3,3,3,3,3`, `3,3,3,3,4`, `3,3,3,3,5`, `3,4,4` (this is `4,4,N` with `N=3` of course), `3,4,3,4`, `3,4,4,4`, `3,4,5,4`, `3,5,3,5`, `3,6,6`, `3,8,8`, and `3,10,10`.

```
|4,4,\d+|4,6,(6|8|10)|5,(5|6),\8
```

Handle `4,4,N` (`N>=4`), `4,6,6`, `4,6,8`, `4,6,10`, `5,5,5` and `5,5,6`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>68</s> 61 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ž‚ÃS2äI{¨.å•3É≠ÞÌδ)Ö“JhG•твŽ6ð9ǝ11Ž
¤š«.¥Ƶ_+ε5L._Dí«}˜€S>I.å~
```

Input as a list of integers.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AXQAi/9vc2FiaWX//8W94oCaw4NTMsOkSXvCqC7DpeKAojPDieKJoMOew4zOtCnDluKAnEpoR@KAotGC0LLFvTbDsDnHnTExxb0KwqTFocKrLsKlxrVfK861NUwuX0TDrcKrfcuc4oKsUz5JLsOlfv//WzYsNCw4XQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##VVG9SsRAEO59inCduIZs9ofYeI0giN2VIRwKglYWghBECScIB1YWFnKKyh0IpyDilWmyRAvh0FfIi8TZyWaTsMvO7Mz3ze/xyd7@0UF5Gvd7TnF14/T6cZmnRXKnLge@msZn2YurZkXyzNS4GD@qB3W9/FxVt0Uy2TncBvvf6PcjT6V63/i@pzRPV7Jp/pTN3Wz2tRiuLRdi1x1uqbdsfv4zKUavg80Y4l2UpAxDRuBEJOQEDkj8o0UQOI3FomqpfdTzOrxKEwatvTWTEUkkSAl/iX9u8CgNJiABSHhNlprDLYcbTsOWyNGYilthA7C3@rGZmnqqCpitWGDPqKONenCxC8IqTdh6pJkMTMFEFqYH0akMaVyHkq1a6kyskx91x8HeqOnRtyxqNb@9k2ZTdlf1Pnironq@@vWJjzF0xHVt0B4GeG7mBZdH0T8).

**Explanation:**

Hard-coded approach.

Step 1: Check if the input is of the type `3.3.3.N` or `4.4.N`:

```python
Ž‚Ã         # Push compressed integer 33344
   S        # Split it into a list of digits: [3,3,3,4,4]
    2ä      # Try to split it into 2 equal-sized parts: [[3,3,3],[4,4]]
      I     # Push the input-list
       {    # Sort it from lowest to highest
        ¨   # Remove the last/highest item
         .å # Check if this modified input-list is in the [[3,3,3],[4,4]] list of lists
```

Step 2: Check if the input is in the hard-coded list of truthy polyhedrons including their rotations and reflections (minus the `4.4.4` and `3.3.3.3`, which are already covered by the `3.3.3.N` and `4.4.N` check):

```python
•3É≠ÞÌδ)Ö“JhG•
            # Push compressed integer 1122222256020285110099101081
 тв         # Convert it to base-100 as list:
            #  [11,22,22,22,56,2,2,85,11,0,99,10,10,81]
Ž6ð         # Push compressed integer 1769
   9ǝ       # Insert it at index 9:
            #  [11,22,22,22,56,2,2,85,11,1760,99,10,10,81]
11          # Push 11
  Ž\n¤      # Push compressed integer 19798
      š     # Convert the 11 to a list [1,1] and prepend the 19798: [19798,1,1]
       «    # Merge it to the other list:
            #  [11,22,22,22,56,2,2,85,11,1769,99,10,10,81,19798,1,1]
.¥          # Undelta it:
            #  [0,11,33,55,77,133,135,137,222,233,2002,2101,2111,2121,2202,22000,22001,22002]
  Ƶ_        # Push compressed integer 222
    +       # Add it to each value:
            #  [222,233,255,277,299,355,357,359,444,455,2224,2323,2333,2343,2424,22222,22223,22224]
 ε          # Map each value to:
  5L        #  Push list [1,2,3,4,5]
    ._      #  Rotate the current integer that many times towards the left:
            #   i.e. acbde → [bcdea,cdeab,deabc,eabcd,abcde]
            #   i.e. abc → [bca,cab,abc,bca,cab]
      D     #  Duplicate that list
       í    #  Reverse each inner integer
            #   i.e. → [aedbc,caedb,bcaed,dbcae,edbca]
            #   i.e. → [acb,bac,cba,acb,bac]
        «   #  Merge the two lists together
 }˜         # After the map: flatten the list of lists
   €S       # Split each integer into a list of digits
     >      # Increase each by 1
      I.å   # Check if the input-list is in this list of lists
```

Step 3: Check if either of the two checks is truthy, and output the result:

```python
~           # Bitwise-OR to check if either of the two is truthy
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž‚Ã` is `33344`; `•3É≠ÞÌδ)Ö“JhG•` is `1122222256020285110099101081`; `•3É≠ÞÌδ)Ö“JhG•тв` is `[11,22,22,22,56,2,2,85,11,0,99,10,10,81]`; `Ž6ð` is `1769`; `Ž\n¤` is `19798`; and `Ƶ_` is `222`.